# Modify number of confirmations

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, blocks, confirmations

By default there are 24 confirmations but I am running a testnet with just 3 miners and I would like to change this number bucause it makes not sense to have 24. I have been checking `transactionConfirmationBlocks` on the following way:

```
const options = {
   transactionConfirmationBlocks: 3
}

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(provider_string, options));
```

I am not getting errors, but when I make a transaction it is still making 24 confirmations. if I check the number of confirmations (`web3.eth.transactionConfirmationBlocks`) is still 24. What is the right way to set the number of confirmations?

Comment: I think the `options` have to be passed as a second argument to `new Web3(..)` rather than `...WebSocketProvider(..)`.

Comment: I did it and it has the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You tryed this?

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const options = {
    transactionConfirmationBlocks: 24,
}

const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545', null, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the options parameter to [Web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html), not to WebsocketProvider, like this:

```
const options = {
   transactionConfirmationBlocks: 3
}

const web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(provider_string),
  null,
  options
);
```

According to [the docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-shh.html#web3-module-transactionconfirmationblocks) it can also be set like this:

```
web3.transactionConfirmationBlocks
web3.eth.transactionConfirmationBlocks
web3.shh.transactionConfirmationBlocks
```